# Should I pass Socket.io-client instance as props or not? (React example)

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-redux, react-context, socket.io-1.0

This is a topic that has been discussed a lot, but everyone keeps saying the opposite of each other, hence I created this question to hopefully clear all doubts.

[This article](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-a-single-instance-of-socket-io-in-your-react-app-6a4465dcb398) teaches you how to pass Socket.io in context. However, the first comment disagrees and even got some claps (saying that one could simply export it in another file, not passing as props).

[Another article](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-managing-websockets-with-redux-and-context-61f9a06c125b) shows you how to use Socket.io with redux, while [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-realtime-app-using-socket-io-react-node-mongodb-a10c4a1ab676/) simply uses the exported Socket.io object.

[The best answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794919/reactjs-socket-io-best-way-to-handle-socket-connection) also shows you that you should simply export Socket.io to use in react. [This article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34) also shows you how to export Socket.io-client and use in react directly.

And so on and so forth... What is the deal here? Can someone please tell me if Socket.io should be passed down as props, or it can simply be imported directly into the components?